# Can't trigger a button using Python Selenium using both Firefox and Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I need to scrape size chart image in a website. The image is placed inside a popup. I am using Selenium, Python to trigger the a href and scrape the data. I have attached my code for the reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.macys.com/shop/product/jessica-howard-side-twist-sheath-dress?ID=11329706&CategoryID=5449'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

#sizechart_popup = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sc-link')
sizechart_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/*[@class="sc-link"]'))).click()

print (sizechart_popup)

# Sleep of 10 seconds irrespective of whether element is present or not
time.sleep(50)
 
# Free up the resources
driver.close()
```

Please help to rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't run a .js file due to some kind of bot detection. I got it to open up by disabling navigator.webdriver.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.macys.com/shop/product/jessica-howard-side-twist-sheath-dress?ID=11329706&CategoryID=5449')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/*[@class="sc-link"]'))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend. How to scrap image from the popup? I tried the following code. But doesn't work for me.

sizechart_popup = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/*[@class="sc-link"]'))).click()
sizechart = sizechart_popup.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@alt="size chart image"]')
print(sizechart)

Comment: URL: https://www.macys.com/shop/product/black-tape-printed-contrast-trim-cardigan?ID=11398979&CategoryID=260&isDlp=true&swatchColor=Neutral%20Animal

Comment: do you want the src? You'd have print(sizechart.get_attribute("src")) from it.

Comment: Yes My Friend, I need the image link

Comment: I got this kind of error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: just switch to driver.find

Comment: File "G:\python-file\test\selenium_dataext.py", line 19, in <module>
    sizechart = sizechart_popup.findElements(By.XPATH('.//*[@id="sizeImg"]/img')).get_attribute("src");
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findElements'

Comment: Shall I raise another question? Do you answer that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810010/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-popup-after-clickable-element-trigger-with-webdriv

Answer (score 0):

try this to find the element and perform click on that particular element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="sc-link"]'))).click()
```