# How to retrieve data from the popup after clickable element trigger with WebDriverWait in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to scrape the image src from this popup. I have coded that but getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findElements'.

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from chromedriver_py import binary_path

import time
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.macys.com/shop/product/black-tape-printed-contrast-trim-cardigan?ID=11398979&CategoryID=260&isDlp=true&swatchColor=Neutral%20Animal'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=binary_path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
sizechart_popup = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/*[@class="sc-link"]'))).click()
sizechart = sizechart_popup.findElements(By.XPATH('.//*[@id="sizeImg"]/img')).get_attribute("src");

print(sizechart)

# Sleep of 10 seconds irrespective of whether element is present or not
time.sleep(50)
 
# Free up the resources
driver.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to download the three images on the left of the given url? or if anything else mention what exact data you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want src of size chart image. It is inside popup. extactly this one https://assets.macysassets.com/dyn_img/size_charts/4011861.gif

Comment: I dont think get_attribute method is applicable for findElements list. Try to use a for loop to iterate through the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using all the available element identifiers if one doesn't work, it worked with `css_selector`.

```
sizechart = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sizeImg > img').get_attribute("src")
print(sizechart)

#Output:
https://assets.macysassets.com/dyn_img/size_charts/4011861.gif
```